# Android add RelativeLayout dynamically

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to insert a RelativeLayout dynamically. The method works well, but the layout is placed laterally and not under the existing

```
 public void Add(View v) {
          EditText et=new EditText(context);
          RelativeLayout dynamic_component = new RelativeLayout(this);
          dynamic_component.addView(et);
        relativo.addView(dynamic_component);

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your layout "dynamic_component" to be auto-magically placed under the existing views of the parent layout, "relativo" the parent should be a LinearLayout with vertical orientation.